# Managing a Distributed Cluster?

Tags: python, cassandra, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Suppose that one has set up a cassandra cluster. You've got a 10[TB] database that is distributed evenly between 10 nodes, everything runs smoothly etc.

Suppose that you have 100 machines at your disposal, each trying to read (different) data from the cassandra cluster. in addition, you have many jobs that constantly need to be run, each job at a different time (and obviously, each job needs to be run on a different machine).

How do you manage all these tasks/jobs? how do you distribute the tasks between the machines? how do you keep track of the jobs / machines in the process?

Are there any open-source tools (preferably, with a `Python` client) that help doing it in a Linux environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a Grid/HPC Framework to handle your distributed infrastructure and to run jobs.

In unix/linux there are two systems that might of good use for you. [Portable Batch Systems (PBS)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/help/os/unix/pbs.html) or [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/)

> How do you manage all these
>   tasks/jobs?

Both Condor and PBS have a master need to act as receptor of every Job/Task, for every Job/Task you can associate level of priority and discriminators. The administrator of the cluster sets up rules based on those discriminators to schedule the jobs.

> how do you distribute the
>   tasks between the machines?

Condor or PBS will do it for you, you only need to submit the job to the master node and specify priority, inputs and outputs, etc.

You can periodically check for when a job is finished, subscribe for notification via different mechanisms or do a sort of `job.wait()` to block till its finished.

> how do you
>   keep track of the jobs / machines in
>   the process?

Both PBS and Condor have `top` alike commands to list jobs that are queued in wait, or running, or cancel. They also have utilities to stop or cancel a job if the process allows snapshots.

For a large cluster, my advice is to try Condor. It's been there for ages to solve problems exactly like they one you have. Here there are [some examples](http://mickcharlesbeaver.blogspot.com/2010/11/i-wanted-to-see-if-i-could-run-python-3.html) for Condor + Python

Other more recent solutions to consider are:

- [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) a distributed task queue for Python.
- [DiscoProject](http://discoproject.org/) a distributed computing framework based on the MapReduce paradigm.

Comment: perfect answer -- exactly what I was looking for. Is `condor` really the way to go? how hard is it to install it / maintain it on a bunch of Ubuntu machines? (I know that once installed, job submission is easy).

how do we handle the fact that (say) we submit a job, the job is being run, and then the machine on which it runs dies? (in such a case, we'll want to re-submit the job to a different machine)

also, can 'celery' for instance be compared? 

btw, I am not limited to only `python`-based solutions, so if you have other ideas, would be happy if you list them. Thanks.

Comment: About celery I cannot say much I have only use it for toy testing, it is cool and very Python oriented. About Condor ... I used it 4 years ago and I remember that it could handle node-fail situation and jobs get re-scheduled see (http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/manual/v7.2/2_10DAGMan_Applications.html#SECTION003106100000000000000) . Condor is not difficult to install and use but it requires medium level on unix/linux administration skills.

Comment: thank you. just one quick question given your experience: does `condor` require password-less SSH between the nodes? or it does not matter?

Comment: I am sure you can configure it with or without it.